# How to convert values of a dictionary list into string?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How to convert values of a dictionary list into string?

My dict:

```
dic = {3: ['W'], 2: ['X'], 1: ['Y', 'Z']}
```

I want output to be as below:

```
out_dic = {3: 'W', 2: 'X', 1: ['Y', 'Z']}
```

I tried with below, but not working. Can anyone help me out in this:

```
out_dic = {}
for key, value in dic.items():
    if (key == 1) | (key == 2):
        out_dic[key].append(value.ToString())
    else:
        out_dic[key].append(out_dic(i))
        
print(out_dic)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a dict comprehension. And using `len()` on value to find size.

**Ex:**

```
dic = {3: ['W'], 2: ['X'], 1: ['Y', 'Z']}
print({k: v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v for k, v in dic.items()})
```

**Output:**

```
{3: 'W', 2: 'X', 1: ['Y', 'Z']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the element of list which contains only one element and put that element as value of dic key.

```
for key,val in dic.items():
 if len(val)==1:
    dic[key] =val[0]
print(dic)
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working fine. The only thing is either we need to take only 'value' or 'val' for all not both. Could you please help me to understand, when we put val[0] why it removes the list [] from W and X ?

Comment: we iterate dictionary. Here each key,value pair is taken as key and val. What I have done is I check each value length since your all values are list, if it has one element in the list we take that element and make it as key's value